# OpenGL in Android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am working on a map engine. I would like to let user rotate the map. If I do the rotation by standard drawing on canvas, it will slow down the phone and the map tiles rotated by standard canvas API looks bad.

I found some OpenGL frameworks for Android on the Internet. But none of them do what I want. Most of them cannot use Android standard components within the OpenGL Activity.

I want to put a custom view that drawn by OpenGL to a Layout component (eg, LinearLayout). Thus, I can put everything (including OpenGL layout) to a Activity. I am sure that it can be done by using standard Android OpenGL API. But the OpenGL draw is too difficult to me.

Is it any OpenGL framework to let me draw a custom view by OpenGL? All I need is a framework that supports simple drawing.

Answer (score 3):

Its called GLSurfaceView.
In one of my projects I have this:

```
public static GLView glSurfaceView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    glSurfaceView = new GLView(this);

    setContentView(glSurfaceView);
}
```

Make sure the class you make extends the GLSurfaceView.

```
public class GLView extends GLSurfaceView
```

In the GLView class you will have to have this:

```
private GLRenderer _renderer;
public GLView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    _renderer = new GLRenderer(context);
    setRenderer(_renderer);
}
```

The GLRenderer class will implement GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Atleast this is what I think you are asking. If not post comment below and I will try and answer it better.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I solved the problem by using standard canvas since the map engine need the 2D rendering only. I am not good in maths (especially bad in Matrix, therefore I dont want to use the GLSurfaceView as I need to handle all matrix calculate myself. Instead, I am looking for a framework like cocos2D that can be use as a View component.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame that you gave up on OpenGL, I've recently discovered it and find it heaps better then doing standard drawing.  Using textures instead of keeping images as Bitmap objects takes much better advantage of device's memory (especially on the pre Honeycomb devices) and if you use an orthogonal projection you don't need to bother with a good portion of OpenGL's fancy 3d stuff. Plus, you no longer have to care (as much) about various devices resolutions so that all the stuff you put on screen is well proportioned (you still have to care about width and height ratio's but that's a lot better).